# Mapbox, get map id for a map that has been created

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, mapbox

So I have a small issue with a map, particularly map style, from `Mapbox` that a designer has created for me to work with.

I have an access to her account and I can view the map as soon as I go in to `account -> styles`. So my question is, how can i reference her design in order to build up on top of this my custom markers and etc?

I have tried downloading a `json` file to find an ID there but no luck. Also tried to copy the stuff from URI when you click on the style, still no ID's. If you need more explanation I can do my best to provide you with one.

So far my `HTML` looks like this.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>A simple map</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.3.0/mapbox.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.3.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <style>
      body { margin:0; padding:0; }
      #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <script>
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'token';
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'ciltdxqbt00jef7m0y99qpkt2')
            .setView([40, -74.50], 9);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution myself. The reason I could not understand why I can get an ID of a map that has been created in editor and not the one that has been created using Visual Studio.

Silly Silly me!

So the only difference is very very small, its just the way you reference it!

**Let me explain :)**

The map that has been created using editor you would normally do something like this:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'accesstoken;  
// map refers to a <div> element with the ID map
// mapbox.streets is the ID of a map on Mapbox.com
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets');
```

Here I am referencing a map with an id `streets` from mapbox, you can get an id when you create your map in editor from url at the very end, for example `https://www.mapbox.com/editor/?id=*username*.ph8b3e4a#saved`

the `ph8b3e4a` would be an id. So to make a map you do something like this

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'accesstoken;  
// map refers to a <div> element with the ID map
// mapbox.streets is the ID of a map on Mapbox.com
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', *username*.ph8b3e4a');
```

But if the map is created in Mapbox Studio, its done like this.

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'accesstoken;
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([38.97416, -95.23252], 15);
    L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/*username*/*style*').addTo(map);
```

this can be copied from right hand side of your styles directory.

I hope this is helpful for anyone who struggles like me :)